# Print to thermal pos printer from web hosted laravel apps

Tags: laravel, pos

I'm working on Laravel oneline based pos system, my system will be hosted in web server and by typing site url end user/client system access our POS from their own pc. Now want to print the order receipt in client  thermal printer. How an I do that? Any guideline will be taken positively. Thnaks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

just connect the thermal printer with the expected Computer from where you want to print.
And write code for print `<br>`

```
window.print()
```

alter you may use the Keyboard shortcut CTRL+P for the print invoice.

Comment: Are you sure it will work when my site hosted in remote server and client using my sites by browsing from their own computer and printer get connected with that client machine?

Comment: I don’t want any popup dialog box for print confirmatio,  it should be direct print based on save button click.

Comment: you are using web. So, there has many ways to just click on button and it will open new tab and print action hit automatically and close after printing automatically.